# Worklight Console protection using LDAP

Tags: ldap, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm able to protect Worklight console with an user inside `worklight.properties` file (on Liberty or WAS environment).

How can I protect console with a LDAP user (outside of the `worklight.properties` file)?

Comment: If the answer below helped you, please mark this question as Answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

You will need to edit your authenticationConfig.xml as follows:

1. Add a [LDAP loginModule](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_ldap_login_module.html)
2. Add a LDAP realm
3. Update the existing "WorklightConsole" custom securityTest to use the new realm

After the above changes, once loading Worklight Console and entering the user credentials, 
these should be handled by the loginModule to authenticate against the LDAP server.

See the following [IBM Worklight Getting Started](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/) training module, which is about this very topic:
[Using LDAP Login Module to authenticate users with LDAP server](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v506/08_05_Using_LDAP_Login_Module_to_authenticate_user_with_LDAP_server.pdf)